# Search and find variable values within html page in java jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, extract, jsoup

In the html page there is a javascript like the below and i want to extract the values of the var number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var number= 4443;
</script>
```

I am using jsoup to parse an html page using this command.

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc3 = Jsoup.connect("http://htmlpage.com").get();
```

How can i do it ? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: can someone help me?... i still didn't find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is a HTML parser, not a JS parser. Best what you could get with Jsoup is getting the HTML `<script>` element(s).

```
Elements scripts = doc3.select("script");
```

Its contents has then to be extracted as text by [`Element#text()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29) and parsed further by a different library which is capable of parsing JS code, such as Mozilla Rhino. You could of course also perform trivial [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) parsing using `indexOf()`, `substring()`, etc methods or perhaps even using some good regex.

Comment: Agreed. If the string you look for is very complex you should prefer Regex to Stringmethods.